# How to update an internal table with another internal table?

Tags: abap

I have this table and you'll notice that column `VKBUR` is empty:

[image: Main table]

What is the best way to populate this column with entries from another table using column `VKGRP` as key?

In summary, I would like to populate column `VKBUR` using data from `L_T_ZCUSTSL04` as source. Their key is `VKGRP` from both tables:

[image: Look up table]

Using this lookup table, I want to pass values from `VKBUR` into the above table.

Thank you so much for your assistance and have a good weekend.

Comment: These are basic operations on internal tables, please refer to ABAP documentation. If you need further assistance, please show what ABAP code you tried, what exact issues you have, and provide the code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with 7.4 or newer, consider the following example based on [`CORRESPONDING`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenconstructor_expr_corresponding.htm) constructor operator.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF gs_report,
         equnr TYPE equnr,
         eqtyp TYPE eqtyp,
        anlage TYPE anlage,
         sernr TYPE serge,
       END OF gs_report.

DATA: gt_msrpoint TYPE SORTED TABLE OF gs_report WITH NON-UNIQUE key anlage.

SELECT equi~equnr, equi~eqtyp, eanl~anlage, sernr UP TO 50 rows
  INTO TABLE @gt_msrpoint
  FROM eanl
  JOIN eastl ON eastl~anlage     = eanl~anlage
  JOIN egerh ON egerh~logiknr    = eastl~logiknr
  LEFT JOIN equi ON  egerh~equnr = equi~equnr.

SELECT equi~matnr, equi~objnr, eanl~anlage, serge AS sernr UP TO 50 rows
  INTO TABLE @DATA(gt_msrpoint1)
  FROM eanl
  JOIN eastl ON  eastl~anlage    = eanl~anlage
  JOIN egerh ON  egerh~logiknr   = eastl~logiknr
  LEFT JOIN equi ON  egerh~equnr = equi~equnr.

gt_msrpoint1 = CORRESPONDING #( gt_msrpoint1 FROM gt_msrpoint USING anlage = anlage  ).
```

Tested and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you need to declare the table or variable gt_measuringpoint1? if yes, would it be the same as gt_measuringpoint?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be same as gt_measuringpoint. You can figure that out just by looking closely at the code. Just add this line to your code and figure out how it works 
`L_T_ZCUSTSL03  = CORRESPONDING #( L_T_ZCUSTSL03 FROM L_T_ZCUSTSL04  USING vkgrp = vkgrp  )`. Note that `L_T_ZCUSTSL04` should be a sorted table with key vkgrp.

Comment: Thank you very much Dan K and I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: If it helped please mark it as an answer so others will find it too.

Comment: `should be a sorted table with key vkgrp` or a standard table with a sorted key :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to fill the table using [table comprehensions](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/30/abap-news-for-740-sp08-iteration-expressions/) and [table expressions](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/29/abap-news-for-release-740-table-expressions/)

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_mara,
             matnr TYPE matnr,
             matkl TYPE matkl,
             maktx TYPE maktx,
           END OF ty_mara,
           BEGIN OF ty_text,
             matnr TYPE matnr,
             maktx TYPE maktx,
         END OF ty_text.

 DATA: gt_text TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_text.
 DATA: gt_mara TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_mara.
TYPES: tty_empty TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_mara WITH EMPTY KEY.

SELECT matnr, matkl UP TO 10 ROWS
  FROM mara
  INTO TABLE @gt_mara.

SELECT matnr, maktx
  INTO TABLE @gt_text
  FROM makt
   FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @gt_mara
 WHERE matnr = @gt_mara-matnr.

  DATA(gt_result) = VALUE tty_empty( FOR wa IN gt_mara ( matnr = wa-matnr matkl = wa-matkl maktx = VALUE maktx( gt_text[ matnr = wa-matnr ]-maktx OPTIONAL ) ) ).
```

However, it has several disadvantages compared to Dan's way, because it requires static table declaration and it creates new itab instead of modifying the existing one. So I recommend to stick to Dan's way.

Of course, construction of new table can be avoided with old good loop and table expression:

```
LOOP AT gt_mara ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_mara>).
  maktx = VALUE maktx( gt_text[ matnr = <fs_mara>-matnr ]-maktx OPTIONAL ).
ENDLOOP.
```